# How to hide and show silverlight user control on main Silverlight Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, xaml, user-controls

I have a main silverlight control named MainPage.xaml in an asp.net web site.

I want to dynamically add and remove control at run time.

So,
I have created another control Top10.xaml and added to selected canvas area on MainPage.xaml as described on this [page(Click Me)](http://www.insidercoding.com/post/2008/07/14/Tutorial-Creating-a-User-Control-in-Silverlight-20.aspx):

Now i need to modify **Top10** visibility in MainPage.xaml dynamically when a button is clicked on MainPage.xaml using C# code in MainPage.xaml.cs.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like the link is not valid any more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for programmability you might wanna set an id for the control u declare in xaml. 
you could say x:Name="top10" or something similar.

on the click event of the button you could use the code below

```
top10.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // to hide
top10.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // to show
```

Hope this helps.